# How to know pthread is stopped?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am new in programming world. I need to move some part of code from kernel space to userland. However, I cannot find the replacement of `kthread_should_stop()` in pThread. May I know how should I use below code in userland?

```
 while(!kthread_should_stop()){
 ...
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: pthread_tryjoin_np function tests specified thread to be joinable, i.e. it's work was done or thread was terminated. see `$ man pthread_tryjoin_np`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magic about `kthread_should_stop()`; the `kthread_stop()` function just sets a boolean variable and wakes up the thread.

Depending on what mechanism you are already using to communicate between threads, you can use a Pthreads condition variable or an eventfd or something like that to implement the stop signal.

Comment: Hi CL,
Thanks for your reply.

How about I using below command to get the pThread's status whether it's terminated or not?

_italic_ **bold**  'While (pthread_kill(the_thread, 0) == 0)
{
    /* still running */
}'

Comment: @909 kthread_should_stop() is querying whether the current thread should stop/exit, while your proposal would be checking whether another thread is still running - which are quite different things.